# Enviar "@Html.BeginForm" para controller de outra area. Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html5, razor

Possuo um *controller* numa `Area` chamada "`LoginProfessional`", com as *actions* `Index, Logon, Logoff`. Eu faço um `RenderPage` chamando a `Index` na `Area` *root* do projeto, porém quando clico no botão que é para enviar o *form* para o *controller* `Home` da *area* `LoginForm` ele envia para o `Home da Root`, sendo que este arquivo esta dentro do diretório de *controllers* do `Login`, porém renderizado na `Root` que possui um *controller* chamado `Home` também. Segue abaixo o código:

Index do Login (dentro do *folder* da Area `LoginProfessional`):

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<div class="container row" style="width: 30%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Logon", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <form class="center-block form-signin" role="form" style="width: 30%; align-content: center">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required="required" autocomplete="on">
                <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Senha" required="required" autocomplete="off">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Entrar</button>

                <nav class="mainmenu pull-right" style="width: 246px; margin: auto; position: relative; max-width: 100%;">
                    <span class="pull-right">
                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-small" href="#registerProfessionalUser">Registrar</a>
                    </span>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </form>
    }
</div>
```

Local no _Layout.cshtml onde renderiza esta página na raíz do projeto (fora das areas):

```
<section class="section" id="professional">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="text-center title">Profissional</h2>
            @RenderPage("~/Areas/LoginProfessional/Views/Home/Index.cshtml")
```

Controller correto dentro da area LoginProfessional:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Logon(FormCollection form)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ProfessionalUser pUser = new ProfessionalUser();
                using (LoginProfessionalDAO dao = new LoginProfessionalDAO())
                {
                    pUser = dao.GetProfessionalUserByEmailAndPassword(form["email"].ToString(), form["password"].ToString());
                }

                if (pUser != null)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(pUser.Name, false);
                    return Redirect("../../ProfessionalUser");
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        public ActionResult Logoff()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
```

Preciso parar chamar o `Logon do Home` dentro da área `LoginProfessional`, não o da raiz, pois ele nem existe.

Answer (score 2):

Resolvi o problema ajustando o nome do controller dentro da `Area` LoginProfessional, pois como era o mesmo nome do que tinha fora (os dois eram HOME) acontecia a confusão no deploy, não deixando de esquecer de também ajustar os `namespaces` do controller.